# UITableViewCell image + saving to Core Data

Tags: core-data, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I display data from Core Data (people). When scrolling through the table, I fetch (asynchronously) the person's profile image from the web and update the Core Data object once it's done as well as the cell's image view.

However, I am running into an issue because `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {` is fired every single time I save an image to Core Data (which eventually slows down the app once the user has scrolled far down). In `controllerDidChangeContent:` I call reloadData on the table view which of course is the reason the frame rates drops drastically.

Any recommendations for how to deal with saving the images to the core data objects once it's downloaded and updating the cell appropriately?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need `-(void)controllerDidChangeContent`? You shouldn't have to call reloadData in that if you are doing you're lazy loading correctly. As I understand it, you are inserting into Core Data, so the table doesn't need to update since the table is what gave core data the image in the first place.

Comment: The data may change elsewhere, so I want to update the table appropriately if changes occur to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can respond to more granular changes in `NSFetchedResultsController` which may help (see example code).

You may also like to take a look at a session from this years WWDC (2012) which discusses how to improve scrolling in a UITableView, specifically techniques that try to limit the amount of processing to just those rows that are on screen: **Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS**

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {        
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I wasn't aware of the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` method, I was reloading the cell every single time I hit the `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` case. Thanks!